# Deleting dynamic partitions completely

Tags: windows-7, dynamic-disk

I installed Windows 7 (64 bit) on my computer; I was trying to extend the 3rd partition into a logical one to install Linux as a dual boot but somehow my disk ended becoming a dynamic one.
I tried reinstalling Windows from scratch, but even the installation process recognized the disk as a dynamic one and didn't let me delete the partitions completely.
I tried a bunch of free tools to convert the dynamic partition into basic but it was futile.
Is there ANY way to delete **everything** on the disk, wiping it out completely?

I have Windows 7 on a USB thumb drive, the hard disk is a 2TB SATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install Linux from another thumb drive, wipe out the existing partitions and then reinstall Windows.

Comment: Once you've installed Linux, use gparted to make sure you've deleted the other partitions. I believe it comes bundled with Ubuntu but you'll have to get it from the repository for Fedora. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use DBAN to nuke the disk, use the quick erase option for the fastest nuke operation.

http://www.dban.org/

Comment: Thanks moab. I went with the other option since I'm comfortable with Fedora

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the Disk Manager MMC snap-in to convert it back to Basic disk?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309044

Comment: The primary partition that Windows was installed on was a dynamic disk itself. The instructions in the msft article involved deleting the volume, which I was not able to do because of it being the OS volume